# Google GCM with Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: android, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

I am going through various options for Push-Notification service use in Android and Windows Phone 8.1 app.

The datapack-size for gcm-push is 4 KB and is ample for my needs and it's also free. Is there any way, GCM be used with Windows Phone 8.1 i.e in the client side ?

I was not able find any proper documentation/tutorial on this.

Other than this, I found a service called PushWoosh. 
What are the pros and cons of this service if compared to gcm ?

Hope some one can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use GCM on another platform, windows has their own [Push notification API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221549.aspx)

Comment: So, is there any unified service which I can use in both ? PushWoosh for example ?

Comment: there is no unified service any library you use leverages each platforms push api, all the library does is bundle it up and handle it for you

Comment: GCM can be used for Ios, maybe there is a way to use it for Windows

Comment: @DonaldJansen Google just recently released support for iOS which still uses iOS push notifications BTW so no there still is no way to use GCM on windows

Comment: Awesome, Im using Windows Push Notifications so its not that bad just hoped there was GCM support for that aswell like IOs

Comment: For those finding this via google - amazon's SNS can push to windows mobile.